# Change prefix of spring.application.name in a custom Spring Boot Starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**I don't want to do this in a Spring Boot Application, but in a custom Starter (Autoconfigure)**

I want to rename the property `spring.application.name` to something like `myNetwork.application-name`.

Is there a way to tell the [ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer.java) to use my property?

I tried to provide a custom ApplicationContextInitializer that extends [ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer.java) and register it in spring.factories

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=\
my.synyx.autoconfigure.MyNetAppIdInitializer
```

This works partially. This ApplicationContextInitializer ist loaded and executed, but always BEFORE [ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer.java), which causes that [ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer.java) is overriding my application id. I tried to play around with the ordering, but neither higher nor lower precedence solved the problem :(

Any suggestions how to solve my problem?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You can always do `spring.application.name=${myNetwork.application-name}`...

Comment: Because i want to provide autocompletion for all required properties unter `myNetwork.`. If it is possible to set the value of `spring.application.name` programatically to `${myNetwork.application-name}` this would be a possible solution. I also tried that, but didn't come to a working solution

Comment: "I also tried that, but didn't come to a working solution".  But How? It should've work.

Comment: I tried to provide a PropertySource that loads the value of my property when  the value of `spring.application.name` should be resolved. Whats your suggestion to do this?

Comment: You don't need that.... YOu are making it overly complex. In the `application.properties` set `spring.application.name=${myNetwork.application-name}`. Which basically states to use the value of `myNetwork.application-name` as the value for `spring.application.name`. And that is it.

Comment: i want to do that in a custom spring boot starter not in an application ( as mentioned in the question title). In a starter there is no application.properties that i can provide for users of my starter

Comment: Then you are a bit out of luck I guess. Also I'm not sure if it is a good idea to change the default behaviors in a starter (which should mianly be about managing dependencies). You could try a listener that sets the value of your property to `spring.application.name` as a system property.

Comment: You're right. I'm doing this in the autoconfigure included by my starters. Starter does only include a pom.xml. But i don't know how to create such a listener. In fact that is my question